# Does This Nested List Comprehension Work?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
def f20(List):
[print(y) for i, j in enumerate(List) for x, y in enumerate(j) if x == i ]
```

This is my code for displaying List[i][i] without using an index, and I wonder if it's OK to write a code like that. The code works for some cases, but I wonder if my code contains any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Changed the title to make my question more clear

Comment: You *should not use list comprehensions for side effects*.

Comment: Also, ask yourself if the code is readable. Will someone else be able to quickly grasp what you had in mind? Will *you* know what it does 3 months from now?

Comment: These aren’t two `for` statements, they’re a nested list comprehension, which is a distinct grammatical construct.

Comment: Also, this question is better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @buran No, this question is about correctness not about style/quality.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I respectfully disagree - the code works and the main question is  _I wonder if it's OK to write a code like that_ (also present in the title) - i.e. style. The next rather obscure and unclear remark _The code works for some cases, but I wonder if my code contains any errors_  doesn't make it about correctness. If this was the case ANY question from code review will fit here - just add something within the lines - _I wonder if my code contains errors_.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make my question clear since English is not my native language. It's completely not readable, and it is very unlikely that I ever write this type of code later. This is just for experimenting, and the question was 'Does this code work?'. Again, sorry for making my question unclear. Thank you very much for your kindness in deciding to help.